# Json format using PHP

Tags: php, json

I want to output JSON like this:

```
[{"item":{"id":"id1","label":"Lorem ipsum dolor 1","checked":false},"children":[{"item":{"id":"id11","label":"Lorem ipsum dolor 11","checked":false}},{"item":{"id":"id12","label":"Lorem ipsum dolor 12","checked":false}},{"item":{"id":"id13","label":"Lorem ipsum dolor 13","checked":false}}]}]
```

I have the following PHP code:

```php
<?php
    $section1['id'] = "id1"; $section1['label'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor 1";$section1['checked'] = "false"; $pie_chart = $section1;

    $section10a['id'] = "id1"; $section10a['label'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor 11";$section10a['checked'] = "false"; $pie_chart1 = $section10a;
    $section10b['id'] = "id2"; $section10b['label'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor 12";$section10b['checked'] = "false"; $pie_chart2 = $section10b;

    $section10c['id'] = "id2";$section10c['label'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor 12";$section10c['checked'] = "false"; $pie_chart3 = $section10c;

    $dashboard['item'] = $pie_chart; $dashboard['children'][] = $pie_chart1;$dashboard['children'][] = $pie_chart2; $dashboard['children'][] = $pie_chart3;

    $output = $dashboard; echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: show the code which you have tried

Comment: Show the code, I think you might be getting results from DB as assoc or API and then try to convert it into JSON. Right?

Comment: Update MY Code plz check

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First, using PHP you could create an array with this structure and after that, use json_encode function:

```
$array = array(
array(
    "item" => 
        array("id" => "id1", "label" => "Lorem ipsum dolor 1", "checked" => false),
        "children" => 
        array(
            array("item"=>array("id" => "id11", "label" => "Lorem ipsum dolor 11", "checked" => false)),
            array("item"=>array("id" => "id12", "label" => "Lorem ipsum dolor 12", "checked" => false)),
            array("item"=>array("id" => "id13", "label" => "Lorem ipsum dolor 13", "checked" => false)),
     )
  )
);

$json_data = json_encode($array);
echo $json_data;
```

Output:

```
[{"item":{"id":"id1","label":"Lorem ipsum dolor 1","checked":false},"children":[{"item":{"id":"id11","label":"Lorem ipsum dolor 11","checked":false}},{"item":{"id":"id12","label":"Lorem ipsum dolor 12","checked":false}},{"item":{"id":"id13","label":"Lorem ipsum dolor 13","checked":false}}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this

```
json_encode($json_variable);
```